# On my Bluetooth LE device, can I change an attribute of a characteristic on a peripheral device?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a UWP app for the Hololens that connects to a Bluetooth Low Energy device. The device I'm connecting to from the hololens is setup as a peripheral device. I can connect to the service and characteristic that I need. But unfortunately, the characteristic only enables the "write" and "indicate" attribute.

**Is it possible to enable the "notify" attribute on a peripheral device from a central device?**

I could use the "indicate" attribute as well, but I read that "notify" would be better because of the high transfer rate I want to use. My other solution would be to adjust the firmware on the peripheral device, but I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server in a BLE system defines and publishes how its characteristics behave. If the server publishes that a certain characteristic is write and indicate, there is no way (without changing the server code) to make the characteristic notify as well.